# How to use NetworkImageView in a ListView

Tags: android, networkimageview

I am new in Android and I got stuck on something.
I have a LisView and I am trying to download images using NetworkImageView, but I can't manage to do it.

I have this in onCreate method:

```
networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbImageUrl);
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache(BitmapLruCache.getDefaultLruCacheSize()));

networkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Can anybody tell me how to do it? I think I didn't understood too well how to use NetworkImageView.

PS: my BitmapLruCache.java

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }}
```

Comment: You might wish to switch to an easier-to-use library, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: The thing is that I have a homework to do and I have to use Volley's NetworkImageAdapter for downloading images from an url.

Comment: NetworkImageView, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to load image into ListView's item, you should do it in the Adapter's [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method. Check this [example](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/misc/PicasaArrayAdapter.java). It should help you.