# Android - Place Image in ListView ImageView from JSON API call

Tags: android

Im new to android and this seems to be overly complicated for no reason at all.

I have a simpleadapter adding data to a list view with 5 values. One of which is a URL for an image. I simply want the imageview to have that image as its source.

Heres the JSON Request

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject dealObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                                String dealTitle = dealObject.getString("title");
                                int dealPrice = dealObject.getInt("price");
                                String brandLogo = dealObject.getString("brandlogo");
                                int dealVotes = dealObject.getInt("votes");
                                String dealRetailer = dealObject.getString("brand");

                                ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.brandlogo);

                                jsonResponse += "title: " + dealTitle + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "price: " + dealPrice + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "brandlogo: " + brandLogo + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "votes: " + dealVotes + "\n\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "retailer: " + dealRetailer + "\n\n\n\n\n";

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                map.put("1", dealTitle);
                                map.put("2", "€" + dealPrice+".00");
                                map.put("3", brandLogo);
                                map.put("4", dealVotes+"");
                                map.put("5", dealRetailer);

                                oslist.add(map);
                                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                                        R.layout.list_item_1,
                                        new String[] { "1","2","3","4","5"}, new int[] {
                                        R.id.title,
                                        R.id.price,
                                        R.id.brandlogo,
                                        R.id.votes,
                                        R.id.retailer
                                });





                  list.setAdapter(adapter);


                                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                            int position, long id) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("1"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                });

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleyAdapter.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
```

Is there no easy way to simply add the "brandlogo" to the "thumbnail"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a quick and easy way to set the image in a View using just the url, then Volley has the solution built in for you.

Replace your ImageView with a com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView and you can easily set the image with just two lines of code:

NetworkImageView:

```
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/brandlogo"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

In your code:

```
    NetworkImageView logo = (NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.brandlogo);
    logo.setImageUrl("http://YourURL",mImageLoader);
```

See the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html).

Comment: Can this be placed before  list.setAdapter(adapter); or where would i add it? Thanks

Comment: The best place would probably be in you adapter's getView(). See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142734/how-to-use-networkimageview-in-a-listview)

Comment: I Must be doing something wrong as there is no getView in the VolleyAdapter. Im using SimpleAdapter also.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I meant your list adapter's getView(). So you might want to override the getView() method of your SimpleAdapter or write your own custom adapter.

Comment: Alternatively, just try setting the url before you pass the NetworkImageView to an instance of SimpleAdapter. That might work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly add image url into imageview. First you have to download that image and then set it in imageview. To download and set image to imageview you can use Image Loader libraries like Glide or Picasso.
Here is the link for Glide

[Glide Image Loading library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

And on how to use this library follow the tutorial given in the link.

Hope this will help